# how do I feed the inputs of network if it has not fed by model.fit?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tensor

I have a simple network in keras and I define a custom layer which does some operations on input tensor and then returns it to the network, but when I want to implement it, it produces the following error and said the input has not been fed while I think when we use fit function it feeds the network. could you please help me with this issue? I could not find a suitable answer to solve my problem. I put my code here too. Thank you.

```
def C(u):
    if u == 0:
        return 1. / np.sqrt(2.)
    else:
        return 1.

def DCT(a, b):
    for u in range(8):
        for v in range(8):
            for x in range(8):
                for y  in range(8):
                    b[u,v] = b[u, v] + 0.25 * C(u) * C(v) * a[x, y]* np.cos((2 * x+1) * (u) * np.pi / 16) * np.cos((2 * y+1) * (v) * np.pi / 16)

def IDCT(a, b):
    for u in range(8):
        for v in range(8):
            for x in range(8):
                for y  in range(8):
                    b[x,y] = b[x, y] + 0.25 * C(u) * C(v) * a[u,v] * np.cos((2 * x+1) * (u) * np.pi / 16) * np.cos((2 * y+1) * (v) * np.pi / 16)

def quntize_mask(window_size: int, keep_count: int):
    mask = np.zeros((window_size, window_size), dtype=np.uint8)

    index_order = sorted(((x, y) for x in range(window_size) for y in range(window_size)),
                         key=lambda p: (p[0] + p[1], -p[1] if (p[0] + p[1]) % 2 else p[1]))

    for i, j in index_order[0:keep_count]:
        mask[i, j] = 1
    return mask
def slicAndJpeg(img):
    for i in range (int(img.shape[1].value/8)):
        for j in range(int(img.shape[2].value/8)):
            temp=(img[:,i*8:i*8+8,j*8:j*8+8])
            tempb=np.zeros((8,8))
            DCT(temp,tempb)
            mask=quntize_mask(8,9)
            qunz=Kr.layers.multiply(mask,tempb)
            tempc=K.zeros((8,8))
            IDCT(qunz,tempc)
            img[:,i*8:i*8+8,j*8:j*8+8]=tempc

class JPEGLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(JPEGLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.supports_masking = True
    def call(self, noised_image, training=True):
        def noise():
#            noised_image = noised_and_cover
            # pad the image so that we can do dct on 8x8 blocks
            pad_height = (8 - noised_image.shape[1] % 8) % 8
            pad_width = (8 - noised_image.shape[2] % 8) % 8

            noised_image_pad = Kr.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(( pad_width, 0),( pad_height,0)))(noised_image)
            slicAndJpeg(K.eval(noised_image_pad))


        # un-pad
            noised_and_cover = noised_image_pad[ :, :noised_image_pad.shape[1]-pad_height, :noised_image_pad.shape[2]-pad_width]
            return noised_and_cover 
        return noise()

#-----------------building w train---------------------------------------------
wt_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(49999,4,4))
w_expand=wt_random.astype(np.float32)
wv_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(9999,4,4))
wv_expand=wv_random.astype(np.float32)
x,y,z=w_expand.shape
w_expand=w_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))
x,y,z=wv_expand.shape
wv_expand=wv_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))

#-----------------building w test---------------------------------------------
w_test = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4))
w_test=w_test.astype(np.float32)
w_test=w_test.reshape((1,4,4,1))


#-----------------------encoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5),activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl1e')(image)
wtm=Input((4,4,1))
#--------------------------------------------------------------
wpad=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda xy: xy[0] + Kr.backend.spatial_2d_padding(xy[1], padding=((0, 24), (0, 24))))
encoded_merged=wpad([conv1,wtm])#-----------------------decoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5),activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_output')(encoded_merged) 
model=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=decoded)
model.summary()
decoded_noise=JPEGLayer()(decoded)#16

#----------------------w extraction------------------------------------
convw1 = Conv2D(64, (5,5),activation='relu' , name='conl1w')(decoded_noise)#24
convw2 = Conv2D(64, (5,5),activation='relu' , name='conl2w')(convw1)#20
#Avw1=AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(convw2)
convw3 = Conv2D(64, (5,5),activation='relu' ,name='conl3w')(convw2)#16
convw4 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu' ,name='conl4w')(convw3)#12
#Avw2=AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(convw4)
convw5 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu' ,name='conl5w')(convw4)#8

convw6 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu' ,name='conl6w')(convw5)#4
pred_w = Conv2D(1, (1, 1),activation='relu' ,padding='same', name='reconstructed_W')(convw6)

model1=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=[decoded,pred_w])

model1.summary()
#----------------------training the model--------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------Data preparesion----------------------------------------

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_validation=x_train[1:10000,:,:]
x_train=x_train[10001:60000,:,:]
#
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_validation = np.reshape(x_validation, (len(x_validation), 28, 28, 1))

#---------------------compile and train the model------------------------------
opt=SGD(momentum=0.99,lr=0.0001)
model1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'imageprim':'mse','wprim':'binary_crossentropy'}, loss_weights={'imageprim': 0.5, 'wprim': 1.0},metrics=['mae'])
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=40)
#rlrp = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=20, min_delta=1E-4, verbose=1)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('sendAct.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
history=model1.fit([x_train,w_expand], [x_train,w_expand],
          epochs=4000,
          batch_size=32, 
          validation_data=([x_validation,wv_expand], [x_validation,wv_expand]),
          callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/home/jamalm8/tensorboardGNWLoss/', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False),es,mc])
model1.summary()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 124, in 
>       decoded_noise=JPEGLayer()(decoded)#16
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py",
>   line 457, in **call**
>       output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>
> File "", line 94, in call
>       return noise()
>
> File "", line 88, in noise
>       slicAndJpeg(K.eval(noised_image_pad))
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 673, in eval
>       return to_dense(x).eval(session=get_session())
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 713, in eval
>       return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 5157, in _eval_using_default_session
>       return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 929, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1152, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1328, in _do_run
>       run_metadata)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1348, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
>
> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
>   'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,28,28,1]   [[node input_1
>   (defined at
>   D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:517)
>   = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,28,28,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]   [[{{node jpeg_layer_1/zero_padding2d_1/Pad/_9}} =
>   _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_39_jpeg_layer_1/zero_padding2d_1/Pad",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>
> Caused by op 'input_1', defined at:   File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in
>   _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console__main__.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       start.main()   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py",
>   line 310, in main
>       kernel.start()   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py",
>   line 505, in start
>       self.io_loop.start()   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py",
>   line 132, in start
>       self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line
>   438, in run_forever
>       self._run_once()   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line
>   1451, in _run_once
>       handle._run()   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 145, in
>   _run
>       self._callback(*self._args)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py",
>   line 758, in _run_callback
>       ret = callback()   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py",
>   line 300, in null_wrapper
>       return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 1233, in inner
>       self.run()   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 1147, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.send(value)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
>   line 357, in process_one
>       yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 326, in wrapper
>       yielded = next(result)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
>   line 267, in dispatch_shell
>       yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 326, in wrapper
>       yielded = next(result)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
>   line 534, in execute_request
>       user_expressions, allow_stdin,   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 326, in wrapper
>       yielded = next(result)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py",
>   line 294, in do_execute
>       res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)   File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py",
>   line 536, in run_cell
>       return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)   File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2819, in run_cell
>       raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2845, in _run_cell
>       return runner(coro)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py",
>   line 67, in _pseudo_sync_runner
>       coro.send(None)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 3020, in run_cell_async
>       interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)   File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 3185, in run_ast_nodes
>       if (yield from self.run_code(code, result)):   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 3267, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 114, in 
>       image = Input((28, 28, 1))   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py",
>   line 178, in Input
>       input_tensor=tensor)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py",
>   line 87, in **init**
>       name=self.name)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 517, in placeholder
>       x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py",
>   line 1747, in placeholder
>       return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)   File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py",
>   line 5206, in placeholder
>       "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 787, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py",
>   line 488, in new_func
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 3274, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1770, in **init**
>       self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value
>   for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape
>   [?,28,28,1]    [[node input_1 (defined at
>   D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:517)
>   = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,28,28,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]   [[{{node jpeg_layer_1/zero_padding2d_1/Pad/_9}} =
>   _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_39_jpeg_layer_1/zero_padding2d_1/Pad",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Comment: Not entirely sure but my best guess is that it's caused by that padding function. Maybe you can pad the data beforehand and let the model assume the data is padded already.

Comment: No, it did not work:((((( I zeropad before sending the tensor into jpeg layer but it produced the same error.

Comment: also when I change this line of code slicAndJpeg(noised_image_pad) to slicAndJpeg(K.eval(noised_image_pad)) it produces this error. if I do not do this, it produces this error ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. that is related to DCT function

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer, the main error is because of `K.eval()`. The error without that line is because of probably this line `temp=(img[:,i*8:i*8+8,j*8:j*8+8])`. try replacing it with `temp=img[:,i*8:i*8+8,j*8:j*8+8]` (without brackets)

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the line `slicAndJpeg(K.eval(noised_image_pad))` in your `JPEGLayer` class. Basically, you're trying to evaluate a tensor by calling `K.eval()` without feeding any data to it. You can't evaluate an empty tensor, right? This can be fixed by removing that `noise()` function completely and do the padding/slicing and other tasks in preprocessing.

Replace the `JPEGLayer` class by following and it should work (Assuming the input data is padded already)

```
class JPEGLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(JPEGLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.supports_masking = True
    def call(self, noised_image, training=True):
        return noised_image
```